# How to change backgroud row color in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have a simple model that I list in the admin, there is a field: etapa which takes a couple of values: `{1, 3, 4, 5, 50, 77}`.

I want to mark all `etapa=50` rows in color RED.

This is not duplicated because I don't want to remark the text like in the posible "duplicated". I just want to fill the row background.

**models.py**

```
class Registro(models.Model):
    ensayo = models.ForeignKey(Ensayo)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    fecha.date_fileter = True
    presion = models.FloatField(blank=False, help_text="Presion", verbose_name="PRESION (Bar)", null=False)
    etapa = models.IntegerField(blank=False, help_text="Etapa", null=False)
    tempin = models.FloatField(blank=False, help_text="Temp IN", verbose_name="TEMP. IN (C)", null=False)
    libre1 = models.FloatField(blank=False, help_text="Libre 1", null=False)
    libre2 = models.FloatField(blank=False, help_text="libre 2", null=False)
    libre3 = models.FloatField(blank=False, help_text="libre 3", null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.fecha

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Registros"
```

**change_list.html**

Any idea?

Comment: This is not the scenario that I'm looking for. I want to mark complete row in color,  this solution just mark the background of the text control and NOT the hole tr. But thanks! I just tried this

Comment: Please reopen it!